# How to write a script file to process this kind of file?

Tags: shell

I have a file like this:

"JE_TUT_M05_W1_009  [ 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ] [ 18774 18773 18773 ] [ 1610 1609 ] [ 14604 14603 14603 ] [ 2598 2597 2597 2597 2597 2597 ] [ 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
JE_TUT_M05_W1_009  SIL                 K_B                   R_I           AE1_I                 SH_E                              SIL"

And each symbol like SIL, K_B, R_I, AE1_I, SH_E corresponds to a []. Now I want to calculate the number of numbers in each[]. For example, for the first SIL, the number of numbers is 1-8, for K_B, the number of numbers is 9-11 and so on. Overall, the final result is kind of like an array:SIL->1-8, K_B->9-11, R_I->12-13, AE1_I->14-16.......
I am wondering how to write script to get the result.

Comment: Please format your question better.  Define first the *syntax* of your input file, e.g. in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

Comment: And consider using better [scripting languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language), such as [guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk), [python](http://python.org/), [ocaml](http://ocaml.org), etc.... The shell is not the best tool for that task. Your problem is a [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) problem, so consider some [recursive descent parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) approach

Comment: Without more explanation, your question is not clear enough and could become closed. A single example is never the specification of any programming task

Comment: @youshin : The whole file consists of a single, long line between quotes???

Comment: 11 hoursa and no feedback to comments. Sorry, but I'm casting the final vote-to-close. You'll need to post a new Q to get any further help on this project. See [ask] and use the `{}` from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to give proper formatting to `code/data/errMsgs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use some language suited for data processing, like GNU awk.

As it is my birthday today and it seems you don't have a clue how to approach this, here is a start:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^ ]+)|(\\[[^][]+\\])"
}
{
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"")
    for(i=2;i<=NF/2;i++) {
        gsub(/^\[|\]$/,"",$i)
        print $(i+(NF/2)) "->" c+1 "-" (c+=split($i,tmp,FS))
    }
}' file
```

Output:

```
SIL->1-8
K_B->9-11
R_I->12-13
AE1_I->14-16
SH_E->17-22
SIL->23-30
```

Comment: Happy Birthday James!

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse_line(input_line):
    my_list = input_line.split(' ')
    my_skip = my_list[0]
    count = 0
    j = -1
    out_dict = {}
    for elem in my_list:
        if elem.isdigit():
            count = count + 1
        if my_skip == elem:
            continue
        if elem == '[':
            start = count + 1
        if elem == ']':
            print( my_list[j] ,"->", f"{start}-{count}" )
            j = j - 1 

input_line = "JE_TUT_M05_W1_009 [ 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ] [ 18774 18773 18773 ] [ 1610 1609 ] [ 14604 14603 14603 ] [ 2598 2597 2597 2597 2597 2597 ] [ 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ] JE_TUT_M05_W1_009 SIL K_B R_I AE1_I SH_E SIL"
parse_line(input_line)
```

Above is python solution. Im assuming, JE_TUT_M05_W1_009 i.e first string appears twice in your input line.

> Output:

```
SIL -> 1-8
SH_E -> 9-11
AE1_I -> 12-13
R_I -> 14-16
K_B -> 17-22
SIL -> 23-30
```